# How can I make a bot that basically makes an embed of a linked site?

Tags: javascript, web, discord, discord.js, embed

I've made a couple discord bots but I'm still very much a novice and I was wondering how I would be able to make a bot that embeds any website (kind of like how YouTube has its video embeds but with text and multimodal elements of a website in one embed) that is posted after the bot's prefix & the command 'site'. I don't know how to make a bot respond to stimulus, and I am not sure how the embed would work. I just want to be able to make it so that any user can type into discord `=site *Enter URL here*` and it would create an embed of the site so people won't skim over links. Here is my code so far, its pretty basic but I have no clue how to implement the ability to embed websites. I know that the site command does not work in the slightest, but these were my attempts:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();

const prefix = '=';

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('WebPress is now online!');
    client.user.setActivity('Microsoft Word 1996', { type: 'PLAYING' })
});


client.on('message', message => {
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/)
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();


    if (command === 'ping'){
        message.channel.send('`Pong!`');
    } else if (command == 'site'){
        const siteEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setURL(**THE URL THAT A USER SENDS**)
            if (!message.channel.first.size()) {
                return message.reply("please give me a website URL to embed!");
        } else message.channel.first();
            message.channel.send(`${siteEmbed}`);
    }

});

client.login('My token here');
```

Thanks for any help you have and enjoy your day! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send an embed with a link you can do this. This will create an embed with a hyperlink in the title.

```
const siteEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setURL(args[0])
    .setTitle("Your desription here");
```

See here for more information on embeds https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#embed-preview

To check if your user actually sends a link you can check if the first argument exists.

```
if (!args[0]) {
    return message.reply("please give me a website URL to embed!");
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly fine to identify if the user sent a URL, but I still need to figure out how to make it so that the URL that someone sends is the URL that is placed into the embed, not a predetermined URL. I plan to use this to create embeds for websites that do not autoembed on Discord, and I'm not sure how to get the URL that someone sends into the ```.setURL()``` section of the code. Thanks again for your help! :)

Comment: You can just use `.setURL(args[0])` but make sure to do this _after_ you check if the URL is given.

Comment: If you are satisfied with an answer you should accept it with the check mark. That way other people with similar issues know what helped you solve the problem 

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that is looking at this, this problem was long-resolved using Pupeteer API to take a screenshot of a website and attach the URL that the user sent. Thanks for the help back then when I forgot args existed lol :D